# Max version for 804

Tags: 2sxc

I have a 9.2 2SXC and I want to upgrade but I don'ty think I can get to the newest version. The DNN version is still 804. What would be the best 2SXC version to upgrade to? This particular site won't be upgrading to DNN 9 any time soon but the 9.2 of 2SXC occasionally eats up CPU, an issue that has been addressed in later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest 2sxc (10.06) supports DNN 7.4.2 up till DNN 9.4. So you can easily install any one you wish. If you want LTS, take the latest 2sxc 9.x, if you want the latest features, go for 10.6. We believe we'll have a 10.x LTS within 14 days from now.